# CustomValidator only called once

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a form control :

I tried 2 different ways

```
    this.passwordForm = new FormGroup({
        oldPassword: new FormControl(),
        newPassword: new FormControl(),
        confirmationPassword: new FormControl()
    })
    this.passwordForm.get("confirmationPassword").setValidators(this.CheckInputMatchValidator("newPassword","confirmationPassword"))
```

and

```
    this.passwordForm = new FormGroup({
        oldPassword: new FormControl(),
        newPassword: new FormControl(),
        confirmationPassword: new FormControl()
    })
    this.passwordForm.setValidators(this.CheckInputMatchValidator("newPassword","confirmationPassword"));
```

There I have the function

```
CheckInputMatchValidator(control1: string, control2: string){
    console.log(this.passwordForm.get(control1).value , this.passwordForm.get(control2).value)
    if(this.passwordForm.get(control1).value != this.passwordForm.get(control2).value){
        console.log("ok")
        this.passwordForm.get(control2).setErrors({notMatching: true});
    } else {
        this.passwordForm.get(control2).setErrors(null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

template

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput type="password" placeholder="{{ 'UPDATE_PASSWORD_PANEL.CONFIRM_PASSWORD' | translate }}" formControlName="confirmationPassword" required>
</mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="passwordForm?.controls.confirmationPassword?.invalid && (passwordForm?.controls.confirmationPassword?.dirty || passwordForm?.controls.confirmationPassword?.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="passwordForm?.controls.confirmationPassword?.errors?.required">
        {{'INPUT_ERR.REQUIRED' | translate}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="passwordForm?.controls.confirmationPassword?.errors?.notMatching">
        {{'INPUT_ERR.INVALID_CONFIRM_PASSWORD' | translate}}
    </div>
</div>
```

but the CheckInputMatchValidator is only called when I create it, and not every time the input changes. What I am missing ? The log appear only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update CheckInputMatchValidator function as below would work.

```
CheckInputMatchValidator(control1: string, control2: string): ValidatorFn {
     return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if(this.passwordForm.get(control1).value != this.passwordForm.get(control2).value){
            this.passwordForm.get(control2).setErrors({notMatching: true});
            return {notMatching: true};
        } else {
            this.passwordForm.get(control2).setErrors(null);
        }
        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: it does work nicely indeed, I am going to check your changes, thanks

Comment: @Hardik Patel, why are you using setErrors?. A custom validator is only a function that return null (if the control is valid) or an object (if the control is not valid). I'am missing something?

Comment: You are right@Eliseo. I just wanted to be in sync with the question so i did not changed anything here.